# Python Multiple inheritance metaclass error

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, metaclass

I am trying inherit `from ABC` and `ctypes.Structure` but I'm getting multiple inheritance and metaclass errors.

What am I doing wrong?

My code is as follows:

```
from ctypes import *
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class FinalMeta(ABCMeta, type(Structure)):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        print("FinalMeta.__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)")
        print("  mcs =", mcs)
        print("  name =", name)
        print("  bases =", bases)
        print("  namespace =", namespace)
        print("  kwargs =", kwargs)
        cls = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
        print("<-- cls =", cls)
        print()
        return cls


class MessageBase(ABC, Structure, metaclass=FinalMeta):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
    
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def format(self):
        pass
```

Error:

```
File "D:\Development\messages.py", line 13, in __new__
    cls = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\abc.py", line 126, in __new__
    cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
TypeError: _ctypes.PyCStructType.__new__(FinalMeta) is not safe, use type.__new__()**
```

Answer (score 4):

This isn't going to work. yAzou's answer might look like it works, but it doesn't - it skips crucial initialization and leaves MessageBase in a broken state, the most obvious symptom being that even if you fill in `_fields_` and implement the abstract property in a concrete subclass, [you still won't be able to create instances](https://ideone.com/87bTWU).

Trying to do multiple inheritance with types written in C isn't well supported. Part of the behavior might be a Python bug, but I doubt it'll ever work well. Here's what's going on.

---

`_ctypes.PyCStructType` is the metaclass of `ctypes.Structure`. This metaclass is written in C, which means its `__new__` is generated as a wrapper around its C-level [`tp_new`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_new) slot.

The `tp_new` wrapper wants to make sure you never skip past C-level initialization by doing something like `object.__new__(tuple)` (or worse, `tuple.__new__(dict)`), because that could cause memory corruption. For that reason, it has [the following safety check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.3/Objects/typeobject.c#L6000):

```c
static PyObject *
tp_new_wrapper(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    ...
    /* Check that the use doesn't do something silly and unsafe like
       object.__new__(dict).  To do this, we check that the
       most derived base that's not a heap type is this type. */
    staticbase = subtype;
    while (staticbase && (staticbase->tp_new == slot_tp_new))
        staticbase = staticbase->tp_base;
    /* If staticbase is NULL now, it is a really weird type.
       In the spirit of backwards compatibility (?), just shut up. */
    if (staticbase && staticbase->tp_new != type->tp_new) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "%s.__new__(%s) is not safe, use %s.__new__()",
                     type->tp_name,
                     subtype->tp_name,
                     staticbase->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
```

This tries to make sure that when you call `ClassA.__new__(ClassB, ...)` with `ClassA` written in C, `ClassA` is the C class furthest down `ClassB`'s inheritance hierarchy. However, it follows a *single* chain of base classes through the `tp_base` pointers, **ignoring multiple inheritance**!

With the way `tp_base` pointers are initialized (see [`best_base`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.3/Objects/typeobject.c#L1974) in `Objects/typeobject.c`), following `tp_base` pointers would usually lead to the most derived C class, but this depends on each C class adding fields to its (single) base class's instance memory layout. `_ctypes.PyCStructType` doesn't do that (it replaces the class dict with a weird custom dict subclass to store its data instead), so the `tp_base` chain for FinalMeta goes FinalMeta->ABCMeta->type->object.

Since `_ctypes.PyCStructType` isn't in the `tp_base` chain, `tp_new_wrapper` thinks `type` is the most derived C ancestor of FinalMeta, and it thinks you should be calling `type.__new__` instead. If you call `type.__new__`, though, you'll skip the initialization this check was supposed to *stop* you from skipping, leaving your class in a broken state.

---

You might think you could fix this by rearranging the bases to put `type(Structure)` ahead of `ABCMeta`, but that only solves half the problem. You'll be able to define your `MessageBase` class, but `ABCMeta.__new__` won't run, and it won't do the initialization needed to mark your `MessageBase` abstract.

Also, there's an entirely unrelated, long-standing issue where even if `MessageBase` *was* marked abstract, you'd *still* be able to create instances of it. The check that prevents instantiating abstract classes is in [`object.__new__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.3/Objects/typeobject.c#L3747), and C classes other than `object` (and descendants of such classes) don't *call* `object.__new__`.